# Order featured and non featured wordpress posts by date

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to order both featured and non-featured posts by date... regardless of the status... I tried the following query and not quite working... I am using TwentyEleven

```
  <?php query_posts('cat=-89&orderby=date&order=DESC');?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way is it `not quite working`? What's the result vs. what did you expect?

Comment: Are you sure that the category `-89` exists? I've never heard of a negative category id before.

Comment: Category `-89` means exclude a the category `ID 89` from the posts... Sticky/featured products are get ordered but they stick to the very top... regardless of the date

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I adopted.

```
query_posts('ignore_sticky_posts=1&posts_per_page=3&cat=6');
```